# Why can't I pass this as a variable to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I'm assigning a member method to an event handler in a class, and I want to do it as elegantly as possible. I thought this would work, but it doesn't - why?

```
class MyMap{
    onMarkerClick(myMap, marker){
        // Do something with myMap and marker
    }

    init(){
        let newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
            map: this.map,
            title: 'New marker'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', (function(myMap){ myMap.onMarkerClick(myMap, this); }(this)) );
    }
}
```

The "traditional" `self = this` approach works

```
class MyMap{
    onMarkerClick(myMap, marker){
        // Do something with myMap and marker
    }

    init(){
        let newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
            map: this.map,
            title: 'New marker'
        });

        var myMap = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function(){ myMap.onMarkerClick(myMap, this); } );
    }
}
```

but I'd like to avoid that pesky variable. Can it be done any other way if I need to access both the `MyMap` instance and the `google.maps.Marker` instance?

Comment: `(function(myMap){ myMap.onMarkerClick(myMap, this); }(this))` I can foresee a syntax error in this case. You are NOT invoking the self anonymous function, the correct syntax would be: `(function(myMap){ myMap.onMarkerClick(myMap, this); })(this)` (note the parenthesis). That said, I would expect this syntax to properly work, unless I'm losing something somewhere else. The clojure, in fact, should ensure that myMap is "known" as an argument on the onMarkerClick custom function.

Comment: @briosheje That doesn't seem to work either - both `myMap` and `this` are `undefined`...

Comment: myMap is, in fact, unncessary (you're inside a class, no need to pass the entire reference to.. itself). That said, either try `.apply` or `.bind` instead of the SIAF. I didn't realize until now what you wanted to accomplish, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of the unnecessary `myMap` parameter - you're using a `class` so the current object *should* always be `this`.  Passing a pointer to the object of interest to a method belong to that same object is a big OOP "no-no", because it's implicitly done for you:

```
onMarkerClick(marker){
    // Do something with "this" and marker
}
```

Having done that, you can bind your event listener thus:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, this.onMarkClick.bind(this, newMarker));
```

The first parameter to the `.bind` call will ensure that your current `this` is actually correctly passed to the event handler (regardless of how the Google Maps API calls it).

The second parameter then gives you access to the marker.

An alternative method taking advantage of ES6 arrow function's "lexical this" is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, () => this.onMarkClick(newMarker));
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for - but I've never seen any examples where `.bind()` is used with more than one parameter before. And to be honest, this feels a bit too obvious and straightforward considering it's Javascript :)

Answer (score -1):

Because you're defining a function with `function` keyword, when defined in such a way it's created outside of your scope which means `this` won't work.

You can instead use `() => {}` definition which will maintain the current scope and you won't have to use `self = this`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', () => { myMap.onMarkerClick(myMap, this); } );
```